# MongoDB C# Driver: Convert time buckets to a dictionary with key as bucket's time

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

We have a collection of documents with the following schema summarising daily transactions.

```
{
  "licenseId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
  "transactionDay":"2023-08-23",
  "startTime": "2023-08-23T13:00:00Z",
  "endTime": "2023-08-23T13:01:00Z",
  "count": 1,
  "size": 12345
}
```

We need to generate a report with the following schema, that provides daily totals of the `count` and `size` fields in a dictionary structure with the key as the `transactionDay` value.

```
{
  "licenseId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
  "usage": {
    "2023-08-23": {
      "countTotal": 1,
      "sizeTotal": 12345
    }
  }
}
```

Using v2.21 of the C# MongoDB Driver, we can generate a report containing daily summaries using the Aggregator Fluent syntax, but not in the format we require.

```cs
var usageReport = transactionCollection.Aggregate()
    .Match(licenseFilter)
    .Group(
        e => e.transactionDay,
        g => new
        {
            transactionDay= g.Key,
            licenseId= g.First().licenseId,
            sizeTotal= g.Sum(x=>x.size),
            countTotal= g.Sum(x=>x.count)
        })
    .ToList();
```

It isn't clear whether we are missing a Projection stage, or whether the approach we've taken in the `Group` is incorrect.

Any pointers or references to how this can be achieved would be appreciated.

Comment: Store numeric value as string in database, really?

Comment: @YongShun I've corrected them. They are demonstration schemas, hand-crafted. I'm new to MongoDB, but not that new :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MongoDB aggregation pipeline should look as below:

1. `$match` - Filter stage
2. `$group` - Group by `transactionDay` and perform the calculation.
3. `$group` - Group by `licenseId` and build the `transactionDays` array.
4. `$project` - Decorate the output document. Convert `transactionDays` array to key-value pair via `$arrayToObject`.

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      "licenseId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$transactionDay",
      licenseId: {
        $first: "$licenseId"
      },
      countTotal: {
        $sum: "$count"
      },
      sizeTotal: {
        $sum: "$size"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$licenseId",
      transactionDays: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id",
          v: {
            countTotal: "$countTotal",
            sizeTotal: "$sizeTotal"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      licenseId: "$_id",
      usage: {
        $arrayToObject: "$transactionDays"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iOyxXIGWZ49)

---

Your model classes for the expected result should be as below:

```cs
[BsonNoId]
public class UsageReport
{
    public Guid licenseId { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, UsageDate> usage { get; set; }
}

public class UsageDate
{
    public int countTotal { get; set; }
    public int sizeTotal { get; set; }
}
```

For the Aggregate Fluent syntax, should be as below:

```cs
PipelineStageDefinition<Transaction, Transaction> firstStage 
    = PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Match(licenseFilter);

PipelineStageDefinition<Transaction, BsonDocument> secondStage
    = PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Group<Transaction, BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument
    {
        { "_id", "$transactionDay" },
        { "licenseId", new BsonDocument 
            { 
                { "$first", "$licenseId" } 
            } 
        },
        { "sizeTotal", new BsonDocument
            {
                { "$sum", "$size" }
            }
        },
        { "countTotal", new BsonDocument
            {
                { "$sum", "$count" }
            }
        }
    });

PipelineStageDefinition<BsonDocument, BsonDocument> thirdStage
    = PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Group<BsonDocument, BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument
    {
        { "_id", "$licenseId" },
        { "transactionsDays", new BsonDocument 
            { 
                { "$push", new BsonDocument
                    {
                        { "k", "$_id" },
                        { "v", new BsonDocument
                            {
                                { "countTotal", "$countTotal" },
                                { "sizeTotal", "$sizeTotal" }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } 
            } 
        }
    });

PipelineStageDefinition<BsonDocument, UsageReport> forthStage
    = PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Project<BsonDocument, UsageReport>(new BsonDocument
    {
        { "_id", 0 },
        { "licenseId", "$_id" },
        { "usage", new BsonDocument("$arrayToObject", "$transactionsDays") }
    });

var usageReport = _collection.Aggregate()
    .AppendStage(firstStage)
    .AppendStage(secondStage)
    .AppendStage(thirdStage)
    .AppendStage(forthStage)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: The above query works if you are filtering documents for specific `licenseId`. In case that the filtering the documents will outcome multiple `licenseId`s, you should look for this [query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oI6LQ7sZySf).